# Spring Cloud Gateway + Keycloak CORS not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, api-gateway

I developed backend microservice application using Spring Boot and put API Gateway in front of microservices. To authenticate users I am using Keycloak.
Right now I am developing frontend application using Svelte, I configured my application.yml in gateway application like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
        add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
```

However, when I am trying to send AJAX request I get the CORS error.

Also I Have spring security (through `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` dependencies). I defined `SecurityWebFilterChain` as:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(); // to redirect to oauth2 login page.

        return http.build();
    }
```

When putting build of frontend in static folder there is no CORS error, but for development I need developer node.js server on localhost on different port.

So, how to fix this cors issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class to define the Cors mapping like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

The example above enables CORS requests from any origin to any endpoint in the application.

To lock this down a bit more, the registry.addMapping method returns a CorsRegistration object, which we can use for additional configuration. There’s also an allowedOrigins method that lets us specify an array of allowed origins. This can be useful if we need to load this array from an external source at runtime.

Additionally, there are also allowedMethods, allowedHeaders, exposedHeaders, maxAge and allowCredentials that we can use to set the response headers and customization options.

***CORS With Spring Security:***

If you use Spring Security in youproject, you must take an extra step to make sure it plays well with CORS. That's because CORS needs to be processed first. Otherwise, Spring Security will reject the request before it reaches Spring MVC.

Luckily, Spring Security provides an out-of-the-box solution:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and()...
        }
    }
```

Comment: In normal world it would be a solution. However, Spring Cloud Gateway is built on top of WebFlux which doesn't have `WebMvcConfigurer`. Also I updated my question with Spring Security config.